# How to solve warning htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in yii1?

Tags: yii1.x

My controller code is below.what is the htmlspecialchars() in this code.

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new TaskAssignDevloper('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['TaskAssignDevloper']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['TaskAssignDevloper'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

my view file code is this

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'task-assign-devloper-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'teamleader0',
    'task0.title',
    'developer0.username',
    'description',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

)); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view file, you have made relations. If the relation doesn't have match to another table then it will give this type of error.

for eg. you you are assigning task to developer and storing the developer id in assign task table but that developer id is not found in users table where you have list of all developers.

for yii 2 tutorials :- [Yii 2 tutorials](http://www.latestphptutorials.com/)